# Blank page for wp-admin after i uploaded the website from my localhost to the live server

Tags: wp-admin, wp-login-form

I recently moved the site from localhost to the live server. And when I try to access the `wp-admin` page I keep getting the blank page and no errors are shown although `WP_DEBUG` is `true`. And when I open the `wp-login.php`, I do get the log-in screen but not able to log in and get the following error:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress

I checked for the  white space after every `<?php` and before every `?>`. I deleted all white spaces but got no success. Please help me out

Comment: Try a different browser and/or check your current browsers security settings (and enable Cookies there).

Comment: i enabled the cookies and even tried in different browser but its still the same

Comment: Have you messed up the cookie constants in your `wp-config.php`?

Comment: there is no mention of cookie constants in wp-config.php

Comment: Turn off all plugins, switch to one of the default themes.

Comment: My mistake, there was a blank line before one ?> in functions.php.Wp-admin is accessible now but now getting white page for wp-login.php after i enter the credentials in the login screen

Comment: Enable debug mode again and see if any error  `>` but now getting white page for wp-login.php after i enter the credentials in the login screen

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your functions.php file:

```
//fix for cookie error while login.
setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN); 
if ( SITECOOKIEPATH != COOKIEPATH )     
    setcookie(TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
```